# if condition executing for AND && in javascript, it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

This is a simple form of 3 fields and I've put condition to check for all empty.

I have given email input in run time, yet this below condition is going TRUE:

```
if ((inputName.value == null) && (inputEmail.value == null) && (inputDate.value == null)){
console.log('empty fields')
alert('All the fields are mandatory')
return;
}
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong in here?

Comment: Without seeing more code it's impossible to say what's wrong.

Comment: We need a more complete code sample.  What is `inputName`, `inputEmail` and `inputDate`?

Comment: `.value` returns a string and therefor won't ever be `null`

Comment: @Andreas That's assuming `inputName` et. al. are input elements.  This can be reproduced with `var x = {};   console.log(x.value == null)`.  Whatever those variables are, they don't have a `value` property.

Comment: @Amy In your example `.value` won't be null either.

Comment: @Andreas And yet the expression evaluates to `true`.  Changing the condition to `===` makes it correctly return `false`.

Comment: @Andreas an `==` comparison to `null` is also a comparison to `undefined`, per the language spec.

Comment: @Amy The magic of falsy values...

Comment: @Pointy I know and I haven't said anything against that fact. I only said that `.value` in `x.value` will be `undefined` as `.value` won't  be null but a string in `inputName.value` o.O

Comment: That expression should never evaluate to true, regardless of what's in the fields: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/n632q5j4/ Add a [mre] to your question.

Comment: @Andreas The point is that in this case, `value` is not a string.  It's not `null` either.  You're assuming those variables are input elements.  They are not, and do not have a `value` property.  It's `undefined`, which is equal to `null` when using `==`.  I'm guessing those variables are strings, not input elements.

Comment: @kopal Could you respond to these comments?  What do your variables actually contain?

Comment: @Amy Hey! sorry, I am kind of new in posting questions so I missed on the comments above. Thanks a lot for all the discussion above. I got to know new things about js.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, instead of null match with ''

```
if ((inputName.value == '') || (inputEmail.value == '') || (inputDate.value == '')){
  console.log('empty fields')
  alert('All the fields are mandatory')
  return;
}
```

Edit: replace && with ||

Comment: I think this would be better code, however the problem is that (according to the OP) the expression is evaluating to true when it should not be.

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues.

The first is that `value` is probably empty string. You can use `!` which handles both - empty string and null/undefined.

The second if all fields are mandatory, then any missing field should trigger the `if` statement, therefore you need the `or`, which is `||`

```
if ((!inputName.value) || (!inputEmail.value) || (!inputDate.value)){
  console.log('empty fields')
  alert('All the fields are mandatory')
  return;
}
```

Also then you should start thinknig how to write it in a way that it is easily extensible. This would do the trick

```
    if (anyEmpty([inputName.value, inputEmail.value, inputDate.value])){
      console.log('empty fields')
      alert('All the fields are mandatory')
      return;
    }

function anyEmpty(arr) {
  arr.forEeach(str => {
    if (!str) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Solution with || won't work in current situation for me. But check for anyEmpty is something new for me. Can you tell what does => mean? I might need it later on.

Answer (score 1):

There is a few ways to check if a string is empty in Javascript. I like to check whether or not it's length is 0.

```js
let inputNameNotEmpty = {value: "test"}
let inputName = {value: ""}
let inputEmail = {value: ""}
let inputDate = {value: ""}

// here, the length is 0. which, in javascript, can be evaluated as a boolean ( false in this case ). That's why we add the boolean operator ! in front of each check.
if (!inputName.value.length && !inputEmail.value.length && !inputDate.value.length){
  console.log('all empty fields')
} else {
  console.log('some fields are empty')
}
```

Comment: Wow that's new, I'll definitely try this check.